# Develop Lotus Notes Database(4.57) by Domino Designer 8

Tags: migration, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

We have been used both Lotus Notes servers and ver-4.57 and 8.5.x. I would like to migrate/copy 4.57 database to 8.5 Server.　The 4.57 Notes servers will be stopped after migratation.
I would like to migrate them for way as follows.

1. Copy Database files(*.nsf files) from 4.57 Servers to Notes 8.5 Server.
2. Change ODS from 20 to 43 of each nsf files.

We would like to modify/fix databases which were copyed from 4.57 (in 8.5 server) by Domino Designer 8 if we received some request to add functions or demand about them.

Is this possible?
Are there any restrictions to use Notes Designer to fix them?

I would like to receive the link/reference or any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notes databases are upwards compatible.

You probably won't run into issues converting databases to a higher Notes version. This is one of the advantages of Notes.

Comment: This is largely true, but over the years IBM has occasionally slipped up on backward compatibility. It's very rare - IBM has been much better with compatibility than any other vendor, but the 4.5 release is more than 20 years old now and a lot has changed. The entire formula engine was rewritten from scratch. It's still important to test your applications before migrating and shutting off the old servers.